# Adding option "Drupal Project" under "New Project" in Netbeans

Tags: drupal, netbeans, netbeans-7, netbeans-platform, netbeans-plugins

Is it possible to add new option under "New Project" in Netbeans so that I can select
New Project >> PHP >> Drupal Project. This will create new project having Drupal files already in it.
Is this possible to do this in Netbean?

Basically automating the task of downloading the Drupal project files and setting it up with Netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility to write netbeans plugins but I don't know about any that does this. But consider using [Drush](http://drupal.org/project/drush) - it's a powerful command line tool that will allow you to download drupal core with one command:

```
drush dl drupal
```

and many other things (clear cache, run updates, download and enable contrib modules etc.)